# Using Bcrypt for a Ruby on Rails and C

Tags: ruby-on-rails, c, hash, passwords, bcrypt

I'm creating a web application that requires the user to sign up and login, and I'm encrypting the password with a salt using the bcrypt library included as a gem.

```
     gem 'bcrypt-ruby', :require => 'bcrypt'
```

The username, password, and salt get stored in the database. I'm planning to make a C API that supplements my web application, but I want the users to login first.  So I want to make a function in C that checks if the username and password exists on the database which requires bcrypt to hash the password again to see if it matches.  I was wondering if I could use the bcrypt library included in this link http://www.openwall.com/crypt/ to do that.

I'm using the library but I'm unsure if it's working or not because I am unsure if the hashing algorithms are the same.

Are all bcrypt hashing algorithms the same?  Is bcrypt-ruby compatible with openwall's crypt blowfish?

Comment: Yes, they should be the same. You can create a hash in language A and verify the password in language B.